# Opening a google doc file with Google Drive on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I can't pass the `Google docs file` link to `Google Drive App` on android.

Is it possible to open a Google drive file on Google Drive Android app by passing the link through intent?

```
Private void open(){
  String link = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/"+FILE_ID;
  Uri path = Uri.parse(link);
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(path, MIME_TYPE);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  try {
       startActivity(intent);
      } catch (Exception e) {
    showMessage(e.getMessage());
     }
      }
```

Comment: Just now i identified the mistake,instead of passing "file id" i have passed the drive id. Now i am able to open the Google doc file on Google drive app.

Comment: Please consider posting your comment as the correct answer to this post for other peoples' reference.